# Logstash gelf logs lost

Tags: elasticsearch, udp, logstash, gelf

(I already asked this questions in [Elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/lost-gelf-logs/79924), but as I have received no answer, I repost it here)

We have 3 hosts with Logstash 2.4.1 and Elasticsearch 2.4.1 on each host, with Logstash configured to receive gelf and syslog/tcp logs.

Sometimes some gelf logs are lost.

- With tcdump I see that the UDP packet reaches the host
- With netstat -c --udp -an | grep 12201 I see the udp queue is always empty
- Logstash is using nearly no CPU (~15% of a core)
- The index queue of Elasticsearch is always empty
- The volume of logs saved to ES is pretty low (<1000/s)

What is happening to my logs?